# How to read a specific language.properties file?

Tags: liferay-7

Here's my problem. I need to generate PDF in particular language chosen by user. Some informations are in language.properties files and I cannot manage to read other files than the current site language.

For example current language is Spanish and User select German. I'd like to read language_de.properties.

I've tried to use:

```
String Lang=LanguageUtil.get(LanguageUtil.getLocale('de'), "Mykey");
```

but without sucess, it always returns "Mykey"

If I use :

```
String Lang=LanguageUtil.get(HttpServletRequest, "Mykey");
```

It works, but It's the site language and not the one I want.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Which language.properties do you mean? The ones from Liferay, a hook, or OSGI module? Or the ones from a portlet.xml (`resource-bundle`)?

Comment: I use languages files, from a module language, global to all the portlets.

Answer (score 2):

*One* option is that you have forgotten to define `de_DE` in your `portal-ext.properties` for `locales.enabled`:

```
#
# Specify the locales that are enabled by default.
#
locales.enabled=en_US,de_DE,es_ES
```

*Another* possibility is that the locale is not enabled for your portal instance. You should check that in the admin UI of your instance.

In both cases `LanguageUtil.getLocale('de')` will return `null` - and this will return the given key from `LanguageUtil.get`. You can verify that by printing the result of `LanguageUtil.getLocale('de')` and `LanguageUtil.getLocale('de_DE')` (should both be `null`). Just add the locale to the enabled ones and you are good.

A *third* option applies, if you have defined the messages in the resource bundle of your portlet (usually you define the messages in a hook or OSGI bundle to use them in more than one portlet). In that case `LanguageUtil.get(Locale, String)` doesn't know which portlet you are in and can't access the resource bundle of that portlet. That's the difference to `LanguageUtil.get(HttpServletRequest, String)`, which retrieves the portlet from the request.

In that case you have to retrieve the resource bundle from the config given to your `Portlet.init(PortletConfig)` method. Or you mimic the implementation of `LanguageUtil.get(HttpServletRequest, String)` with a locale specific parameter:

```
public class MyLanguageUtil {

  public static String get(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale, String key) {
    if (request == null) {
      return key;
    }

    PortletConfig portletConfig = (PortletConfig) request.getAttribute("javax.portlet.config");
    if (portletConfig != null) {
      ResourceBundle resourceBundle = portletConfig.getResourceBundle(locale);
      if (resourceBundle.containsKey(key)) {
        return LanguageUtil.get(resourceBundle, key, key);
      }
    }

    return LanguageUtil.get(locale, key);
  }

}
```

Comment: locales are active , I've choosen only nl, es, fr and en. My files are named for example Language_fr.properties. Locale selloc= LanguageUtil.getLocale("es"); is not null, i get es_ES

Comment: I added a third option.

Answer (score 1):

ok got it to work.
I added a class for each language in my module language

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.language.UTF8Control;

@Component(
        property = { "language.id=es_ES" }, 
        service = ResourceBundle.class
    )
public class EsResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return _resourceBundle.getObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return _resourceBundle.getKeys();
    }
private final ResourceBundle _resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
    "content.Language_es_ES", UTF8Control.INSTANCE);}
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

For those who need this to be a little more generic.

Add a small class to your portlet that accesses the portlets ResourceBundle:

```
public class [MyPortlet]LanguageUtil {

    public static String get (Locale locale, String key) {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("content.Language", locale, UTF8Control.INSTANCE);
        
        return LanguageUtil.get(resourceBundle, key);
    }
    
    public static String format (Locale locale, String pattern, Object[] arguments) {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("content.Language", locale, UTF8Control.INSTANCE);
        
        return LanguageUtil.format(resourceBundle, pattern, arguments);
    }
}
```

and export it with the help of the bnd.bnd file of the portlet like:

```
Export-Package: [path.to.my.util]
```

This way it can be used in OSGI modules and regular JAVA classes for example like this:

```
[MyPortlet]LanguageUtil.get(serviceContext.getLocale(), "my-language-string");
```